# How to Multi-Screen android tablet application on Adobe AIR and Flash Professional

Tags: android, flash, air, adobe, multiscreen

I have done app in ipad with Adobe AIR thats work fine in ipad,

but now i have to create android tablet app for multiscreen resolution like this,

2560*1600, 1366*768, 1280*800, 1280*768, 1024*768, 1024*600, 960*640, 960*540, 854*480, 800*600, 800*480, 800*400

and my current .fla file resolution is 1024*768 so how can i create android tablet app with multi-screen?

thanks

Comment: Just a quick question, which tablet device has 2560x1600? 1920x1200 seems much more, well lets say common - the Transformer Prime had such a thing, but who's got one of those? ;).

Answer (score 1):

I think there is two ways in short:

One is to detect screen resolution and than according to it scale all vector content and convert to bitmaps with a code. Check good article from Adobe: http://www.adobe.com/devnet/air/articles/multiple-screen-sizes.html

Second way to prepare pre-created bitmaps for every different resolution and use them accordingly.